# Changing checkbox value when div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, cordova

I have a checkbox which when clicked saves the value along with its title in the local storage. This checkbox is inside a div. I want the checkbox value to change when anywhere in the div is clicked but I could not figure out how to do it. This is my code so far.

```html
<div class="grid-menu">
    <div class="centering-and-alignment" ng-repeat="row in items | partition:3">

        <div class="grid-menu-item list__item list__item--tappable" ng-repeat="item in row">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" name="item.title" ng-change="SaveCategories()">

                <div class="checkbox__checkmark"></div>
            </label>
            <ons-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ons-icon>
            <div class="grid-menu-item-label">{{item.title}}</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing

```html
<div class="grid-menu-item list__item list__item--tappable" ng-repeat="item in row" >
```

to

```html
<div class="grid-menu-item list__item list__item--tappable" ng-repeat="item in row" ng-click="item.value = !item.value" >
```

it works but however it does not save the values to the local storage, so everything is unchecked when I open the page again.

I looked at other similar questions but they do not involve localstorage.

Comment: Try changing the div to `<div class="grid-menu-item list__item list__item--tappable" ng-repeat="item in row" ng-click="item.value = !item.value;SaveCategories()" >` -- Call "SaveCategories()" when it is clicked.

Comment: your method worked! thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to make use of additional labels. For this you would modify markup a little:

```
<div class="grid-menu-item list__item list__item--tappable" ng-repeat="item in row">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-{{$index}}" ng-model="item.value" name="item.title" ng-change="SaveCategories();">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark">{{item.value}}</div>
    </label>
    <label for="check-{{$index}}">
        <ons-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ons-icon>
    </label>
    <div class="grid-menu-item-label">
        <label for="check-{{$index}}">{{item.title}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```